# Distance between the middle point of BC and the foot of the perpendicular from A is$\frac{b^2-c^2}{2a}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Prove that the distance between the middle point of BC and the foot of the perpendicular from A is$\frac{b^2-c^2}{2a}$.

I found the length of $AM^2=\frac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{4}$ using Stewart theorem.I also found $AD^2$ using Stewart theorem but that is coming in terms of $\tan B$ and $\tan C$.If AD had come in terms of $a,b,c$,I would have solved the question using Pythagoras theorem.

Is my approach correct,if not how can i solve this question?Please help.....

Comment: Be more precise. What are $A,B,C,D,a,b,c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$c^2=BH^2+AH^2 \to  c^2=(\frac{a}{2}-HM)^2+AH^2 $$
$$b^2=CH^2+AH^2 \to  b^2=(\frac{a}{2}+HM)^2+AH^2 $$find $b^2-c^2$
$$b^2-c^2= (\frac{a}{2}+HM)^2+AH^2 -((\frac{a}{2}-HM)^2+AH^2 )=\\\frac{a^2}{4}+2\frac{a}{2}.HM +HM^2 +AH^2 -(\frac{a^2}{4}-2\frac{a}{2}.HM +HM^2 +AH^2)=2a.HM \\ \to \\HM=\frac{b^2-c^2}{2a}$$